# How to pass in double value via jmeterproperty in Jmeter

Tags: java, bash, jmeter

I am trying to parametrize some values in the Precise Throughput Timer. So that this can be passed when jmeter is run from the command line.

The xml snippet is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PreciseThroughputTimer guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="PreciseThroughputTimer" testname="Precise Throughput Timer" enabled="true">
   <doubleProp>
      <name>allowedThroughputSurplus</name>
      <value>1.0</value>
      <savedValue>0.0</savedValue>
   </doubleProp>
   <intProp name="exactLimit">10000</intProp>
   <doubleProp>
      <name>throughput</name>
      <value>${req_per_sec}</value> <!-- variable -->
      <savedValue>0.0</savedValue>
   </doubleProp>
   <intProp name="throughputPeriod">1</intProp>
   <longProp name="duration">60</longProp>
   <intProp name="batchSize">1</intProp>
   <intProp name="batchThreadDelay">0</intProp>
   <longProp name="randomSeed">0</longProp>
</PreciseThroughputTimer>
```

and then I pass the value in when jmeter is started via:

```sh
...
--jmeterproperty req_per_sec=${REQ_PER_SEC} \
...
```

Where `REQ_PER_SEC` is a bash environment variable... But this fails to run with the following error:

```sh
An error occurred: Error in NonGUIDriver Problem loading XML from:'/jmeter/test.jmx'.
Cause:
NumberFormatException: For input string: "${req_per_sec}"

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       :
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:105)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/PreciseThroughputTimer/doubleProp[2]/value
line number         : 90
version             : 5.3
-------------------------------
```

Looking into the logs I also see this:

```sh
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${req_per_sec}"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502) ~[?:1.8.0_252]
```

It seems Jmeter is reading the value as a string instead of a double? I cant figure out how to make it get the value passed in via the `jmeterproperty` property as double.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the syntax of a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) while you're setting a **JMeter Property**.

You need to either change your `${req_per_sec}` to [__P() function call](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

```
${__P(req_per_sec,)}
```

or add [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element and declare `req_per_sec` global variable with the value of `${__P(req_per_sec,)}` if you're using this `${req_per_sec}` variable in more than one place:

[image]

Comment: I changed to `${__P(req_per_sec,)}` but still getting the error :(